# How to show and change Image inside a Flask Route?

Tags: python, image, flask, pdf, path

I am Trying to build a Library Management System using flask. The idea is there will be a homepage, where when clicked on a book, we will be redirected to a reader(also written in HTML), which will show the images of the pages of the book.

[Home Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4po6.png)
[Reader Page, Image will be shown on the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4O4LN.png)

The Backend and Book Logic is written with python & Pandas.

In order to open the reader with the images of different books, I have to route each div through '/reader'+id, where each div's id is the id of the concerned pdf.

```
<main>
        {% for book in books %}
        <div class="container" >
            <div class="inner-containers" id="{{book['ID']}}" onclick="showReader('{{book['ID']}}')">
                <div class="image-container">
                    <img class="book-image" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='thumbnails/' + book['Image']) }}">
                </div>
                <div class="book-details">
                    <p class="name">{{ book['Name'] }}</p>
                    <p class="author">{{ book['Author'] }}</p>
                    <p class="details">{{ book['Date'] }} &#183; {{ book['Genre'] }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </main>
```

```
@app.route('/reader/<book_id>')
def reader(book_id):
    book_row = books_df[books_df['ID'] == book_id]
    if not book_row.empty:
        last_page = book_row['Last_page'].idxmax()
        last_page_image_path =  str(pdf_to_image("Server/Books/"+str(book_row.iloc[0]['Name']+".pdf"), last_page, 150))
        print(f"Path to Image: {last_page_image_path}")
        return render_template('reader.html', book_id=book_id, last_page_image=last_page_image_path)
    else:
        return "Book not found"
```

I am attaching the link to all the files based on the way they are in my directory and a description of each file is given below. However the code is unable to find the image of the last read page and showing up this error
"GET /reader/static/Images/1.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
Even when i make another folder called reader, it doesn't seem to be working.
[Link to my Project:](https://github.com/recursioncat/Test_LIbrary_Management)

```
Backend_Scripts

 -rendered.py (contains logic to convert page into image)

 -Basic_logic.py (Contains Book and Library Classes)

Server

 -books(folder)

 -.lib (datafile, books table)

static

 -icons

  --icons files

 -Images

  --this is where i want to generate the pages

 -Thumbnails

  --Book Thumbnails

 -CSS Files

templates

 -main.html

 -reader.html

app.py
```

Please be gentle and Thank you